# RadioButtonFor Usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Here is my code:

**_testPartial.cshtml(Partial view)**

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.CardType, "G", new { @checked = @Model.IsGold})
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.CardType, "P", new { @checked = @Model.IsPlatinum})
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.CardType, "B", new { @checked = @Model.IsBusiness})
```

**Controller**

```
public PartialViewResult ShowCardtype() 
{ 
    Model cardType= new Model {
    IsGold=true,
    IsPlatinum=false,
    IsBusiness=false};

    return PartialView("_testPartial",cardType);
}
```

The expected behavior is, the GOLD radio button option should have been selected in the form. But it always selects the last option. I tried returning "checked" string, but no luck. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the second option is the selected option,  you don't need the new part.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.CardType, "G") 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.CardType, "P") 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.CardType, "B")
```

when you load the view set model.CardType to G, P, or B and it will select the correct radio button

Comment: Thank you, it works. Just curious, so whats is the right scenario to use the @checked attribute?

Comment: if you don't use a for helper then you can use the checked to set a default.  I have found with the for helper that most of the parameters are overridden so you can't customize much

Comment: Thanks @Matt Bodily, i have been scratching my head for the past 2 days, and your simple answer resolved mine, as well.